# Why is SpriteKit's showFields property not working properly?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

Building a game in SpriteKit, I used [`SKFieldNode.radialGravityField()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skfieldnode/1520382-radialgravityfield) with negative `strength` to simulate a positive charge's electric field. To visualize the fields and their interaction, I used [`SKView.showFields`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skview/1520443-showsfields) property and it was working fine.

Now, trying to implement a negative charge, I tried switching all fields to [`SKFieldNode.electricField()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skfieldnode/1520396-electricfield). The behavior of the fields and particles (attraction and repulsion) continued to work perfectly, but the visual representation created by `showFields` stopped working.

Investigating, the visual representation worked only for `radialGravityField` and did nothing for all other [`SKFieldNode`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skfieldnode/) options. I tried changing the fields' strength but couldn't reach anything. In addition to the fields physics working fine, I looked for the fields magnitude using [`SKPhysicsWorld.sampleFields(at:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skphysicsworld/1449627-samplefields) and they were correct.

### Example

Based on XCode's default project for iOS game, this `GameScene` below can reproduce the behavior. Changing from `SKFieldNode.radialGravityField()` to `SKFieldNode.electricField()` makes the fields not show up.

```swift
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

    private var fieldNode : SKFieldNode?
    
    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        view.showsFields = true
        
        self.fieldNode = SKFieldNode.radialGravityField() // Change field type here
        
        if let fieldNode = self.fieldNode {
            fieldNode.strength = 2
        }
    }

    func touchDown(atPoint pos : CGPoint) {
        if let n = self.fieldNode?.copy() as! SKFieldNode? {
            n.position = pos
            self.addChild(n)
        }
    }
    
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        for t in touches { self.touchDown(atPoint: t.location(in: self)) }
    }
}
```

Comment: The `showFields` debug property is broken. See https://feedbackassistant.apple.com/feedback/9654037

Comment: @Calin the link gives me "Feedback not found"

Comment: Looks like feedback links are private to the team. There has been a bug report filed with Apple 7 months ago, as instructed by an Apple engineer. See https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/690730. If you can add your comments there, maybe that will make it more visible and Apple will do something about it.

Comment: Did it. Wondering if anyone has implemented a field visualizer like this in SpriteKit.

Comment: Re: showFields  (for gravity) If you set your scene anchor point to 0,0 (instead of 0.5,0.5) then the field will fill the entire scene.  Needless to say it's very hard to see when there are no gravitational forces applied being exerted, as the vectors are all pointed directly upwards.